# Is it possible to receive notifications when a comment is added to a TFS Git pull request?

Tags: git, tfs, pull-request

My team uses a Git team project with TFS 2013 Update 4. Email notifications are sent out as expected when a pull request is created or a branch under review is updated. However, notifications aren't sent when a comment is added to the pull request - is it possible to enable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the 5/11/2017 release, users now get notifications for comments on PRs they create or have participated in.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2017/may-11-team-services#default-notifications-for-pr-comments

Answer (score 13):

I don't believe that is currently possible, but it is a good idea. You should head over to http://visualstudio.uservoice.com and add it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I went ahead and added one: [Notify owner/reviewers when a new comment is added to a Git pull request](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/8191560-notify-owner-reviewers-when-a-new-comment-is-added).

Comment: I don't understand how this is not available?!?! I don't use TFS often, but what do people do who use a pull-request workflow?! I'm not even on a distributed team, and it's impossible to track when comments are added to pull requests! So frustrating!!!!

Comment: Don't you talk with your team ThePuzzleMaster?

Comment: This is a feature that is really needed because you may have tons of things to talk about to your team. Or maybe add a tag feature like "@" to create a notification for a team member